# Ajax call in Rails producing duplicate information and not showing in page correctly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I'm making an app where a student can click on a check box to say they've attended their class. I'm trying to do this with an ajax call, and update the same page in real time. So far I'm able to get the information correctly in the database, but I'm having two errors. One error is that the the student's name display's twice on the view (after a hard refresh), and the second is the code doesn't show the results in real time on the page. How do I fix these errors? Any help here would be greatly appreciated, I've stuck on this for awhile. Here is the code I have so far...

lecture.html.erb (view page, lectures show page)

```
<h1>Lecture Profile</h1>
<h3><%= @lecture.name %></h3>
<p>Start Time: <%= @lecture.start_time %></p>
<p>End Time: <%= @lecture.end_time %></p>
<p>Notes: <%= @lecture.notes %></p>
<div>
  <p><%= link_to "Edit Lecture", "/lectures/#{@lecture.id}/edit" %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Delete Lecture", "/lectures/#{@lecture.id}", method: :delete, data:{confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this lecture"} %></p>
</div><br>

<%= form_for @attendance, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: "/attendances/form", locals: {f: f} %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :arrived, value: Time.now %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, value: current_student.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :lecture_id, value: @lecture.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<h2>Students Attended</h2>
  <%= render partial: "/attendances/index", locals:{attendances: @attendances}%>
```

_form.html.erb (form for new attendance)

```
<div id="attended-checkbox">
  <%= f.label current_student.friendly_name %>
  <%= f.label :attended %>
  <%= f.check_box :attended %>
</div>
```

_index.html.erb (view template that's rendered for displaying students that have attended the course)

```
<div class="lectures-attended-students" id="attendance_<%= @attendance.id %>"> 
  <% @attendances.each do |attendance| %>
    <% attendance.lecture.cohort.students.each do |student| %>
      <% student.attendances.each do |a|%>
        <% if a.attended == true %>
           <p><%= student.friendly_name %></p>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

attendances controller

```
class AttendancesController < ApplicationController

  def new

  end

  def create
    @attendance = Attendance.new(attendance_params)
    @lecture = Lecture.find_by(id: params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @attendance.save
        format.html { redirect_to '/lectures/@lecture.id', notice: 'Attendance was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @attendance }
        format.js
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @attendance.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  private

    def attendance_params
      params.require(:attendance).permit(
        :arrived,
        :attended,
        :lecture_id,
        :student_id
      )
    end

end
```

lectures controller

```
class LecturesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @lecture = Lecture.new
    @cohort = Cohort.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def create
    @lecture = Lecture.new(lecture_params)

    if @lecture.save
      flash[:success] = "Successfully created new lecture"
      redirect_to "/cohorts/#{@lecture.cohort_id}"
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Lecture Not Created"
      render :new
    end
  end

  def show
    @lecture = Lecture.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @attendance = Attendance.new
    @attendances = Attendance.all
  end

  def edit
    @lecture = Lecture.find_by(id: params[:id])
  end

  def update
    @lecture = Lecture.find_by(id: params[:id])

    if @lecture.update(lecture_params)
      flash[:success] = "Successfully updated lecture"
      redirect_to "/cohorts/#{@lecture.cohort_id}"
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Lecture Not Updated"
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @lecture = Lecture.find_by(id: params[:id])
    cohort_id = @lecture.cohort_id
    @lecture.destroy
    flash[:success] = "Your lecture has been deleted"
    redirect_to "/cohorts/#{cohort_id}"
  end

  private

    def lecture_params
      params.require(:lecture).permit(
        :name,
        :start_time,
        :end_time,
        :notes,
        :cohort_id
      )
    end
end
```

create.js.erb

```
$("#attended-checkbox").val('');

$(".lectures-attended-students").prepend('<%= j render @attendance');
```

After checking the box and clicking the submit button, the terminal returns this error

```
attendances/create.js.erb:7: syntax error, unexpected tSTRING_BEG, expecting keyword_do or '{' or '('
...$(".lectures-attended-students").prepend(\''.freeze;@output_...
```

After clicking the refresh button on the view page, the terminal shows this

```
Started GET "/lectures/1" for ::1 at 2016-08-25 11:50:33 -0500
Processing by LecturesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  Lecture Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "lectures".* FROM "lectures" WHERE "lectures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Student Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Rendered attendances/_form.html.erb (8.0ms)
  Attendance Load (0.7ms)  SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances"
  Lecture Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "lectures".* FROM "lectures" WHERE "lectures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  Cohort Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "cohorts".* FROM "cohorts" WHERE "cohorts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  Student Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."cohort_id" = $1  [["cohort_id", 5]]
  Attendance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 5]]
  Attendance Load (0.3ms)  SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 7]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT  "lectures".* FROM "lectures" WHERE "lectures"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
  CACHE (0.1ms)  SELECT  "cohorts".* FROM "cohorts" WHERE "cohorts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "students".* FROM "students" WHERE "students"."cohort_id" = $1  [["cohort_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 5]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "attendances".* FROM "attendances" WHERE "attendances"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 7]]
  Rendered attendances/_index.html.erb (25.2ms)
  Rendered lectures/show.html.erb within layouts/application (52.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 311ms (Views: 290.8ms | ActiveRecord: 3.8ms)
```

The view prior to submission (Test Test is the student's name)

```
Lecture Profile
Routing
Start Time: 2016-08-31 18:00:00 UTC

End Time: 2016-08-31 21:30:00 UTC

Notes: Intro to Rails routing.

Edit Lecture

Delete Lecture


Test test Attended  
Submit
Students Attended

Test45 Test45
```

The actual display on local host post submission and hard refresh. (Displays three names, instead of the one new name. This includes the previously submitted name, as well as the new name twice)

```
Lecture Profile
Routing
Start Time: 2016-08-31 18:00:00 UTC

End Time: 2016-08-31 21:30:00 UTC

Notes: Intro to Rails routing.

Edit Lecture

Delete Lecture


Test test Attended  
Submit
Students Attended
Test Test

Test45 Test45

Test Test

Test45 Test45
```

EDIT:---------------------------------------------------------------------

These changes have fixed the repeating data error in the hard refresh, but now I'm dealing with a nil class error for the ajax request. I don't understand how I'm not passing in a lecture.

lecture.rb (Changed lecture model to this)

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cohort
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_students, through: :attendances, source: :student
end
```

_attendance.html.erb (Was Changed To This)

```
<div class="lectures-attended-students" id="attendance_<%= @attendance.id %>"> 
  <% @lecture.attended_students.each do |student| %>
    <p><%= student.friendly_name %></p>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

show.html.erb (Lectures Show Page Now Looks Like This)

```
<h1>Lecture Profile</h1>
<h3><%= @lecture.name %></h3>
<p>Start Time: <%= @lecture.start_time %></p>
<p>End Time: <%= @lecture.end_time %></p>
<p>Notes: <%= @lecture.notes %></p>
<div>
  <p><%= link_to "Edit Lecture", "/lectures/#{@lecture.id}/edit" %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Delete Lecture", "/lectures/#{@lecture.id}", method: :delete, data:{confirm: "Are you sure you want to delete this lecture"} %></p>
</div><br>

<%= form_for @attendance, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= render partial: "/attendances/form", locals: {f: f} %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :arrived, value: Time.now %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :student_id, value: current_student.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :lecture_id, value: @lecture.id %>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit" %>
<% end %>

<h2>Students Attended</h2>
  <%= render partial: @attendance, locals:{lecture: @lecture}%>
```

create.js.erb (Now looks like this)

```
$("#attended-checkbox").val('');

$(".lectures-attended-students").prepend('<%= j render @attendance, locals:{lecture: @lecture} %>');
```

Here is what the terminal is giving me

```
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 42ms (ActiveRecord: 9.4ms)

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `attended_students' for nil:NilClass):
    1: <div class="lectures-attended-students" id="attendance_<%= @attendance.id %>"> 
    2:   <% @lecture.attended_students.each do |student| %>
    3:     <p><%= student.friendly_name %></p>
    4:   <% end %>
    5: </div>
  app/views/attendances/_attendance.html.erb:2:in `_app_views_attendances__attendance_html_erb__505249290825397873_70333903626520'
  app/views/attendances/create.js.erb:3:in `_app_views_attendances_create_js_erb__3555789531505990218_70333854235700'
  app/controllers/attendances_controller.rb:11:in `create'
```

Comment: Are both Test Test and Test45 Test45 student names? Your view example is somewhat confusing. Can you provide a screen shot? One thing I see right of the bat is that this erb tag is not properly closed: `$(".lectures-attended-students").prepend('<%= j render @attendance');` . If I understand, the duplicate students appear even after a hard refresh?

Comment: Yes Test Test and Test45 Test45 are the names of two different students. ie Test Test if the first and last name of one student, Test45 Test45 is the first and last name of another student. The .friendly_names is a model method that combines first and last names. The duplicate students appear after a hard refresh, a single copy of a previously created student is made again, and two copies of the newly created student are made.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem may be here:

```
<% @attendances.each do |attendance| %>
    <% attendance.lecture.cohort.students.each do |student| %>
      <% student.attendances.each do |a|%>
        <% if a.attended == true %>
           <p><%= student.friendly_name %></p>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

You are querying for all attendances and iterating through each one, and then going back to to the attendances from the students. For each attendance you are printing all students with attendances. In this case you have 2 attendances so you have 2 entries for each student. Nested loops with active record queries like this can be messy and are bad practice as they make multiple calls to the DB. They should be avoided. Look into the n+1 query problem.

An attendance is really just a join between a lecture and student, so why not use that relationship to build your query? There are number of ways you could do this. You could try and write a clearer one liner using [joins](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joins) that will give you only the data you want. Adding has_many through relation on a model will essentially build this for you. Since it appears that you already have a lecture object available from you controller and in your lecture show page, you could create a relationship in your lecture model that returns the students who have attend that lecture. it might something like this:

in app/models/lecture.rb

```
class Lecture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :attendances
  has_many :attended_students, through: :attendances, class_name: "Student"
end
```

in app/models/attendance.rb

```
class Attendance < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :student
  belongs_to :lecture
end
```

in app/views/lectures/show.html.erb

```
<ul>
<% @lecture.attended_students.each do |student| %>
  <li><%=student.friendly_name%></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
```

If you corrected the problem with missing erb tag that I mentioned in the comment, ajax should work for you as well.

Comment: Thank you. The duplicate data problem has been solved, I never new about  source in rails models, so thank you for leading me to that. The ajax call is unfortunately not working. I've added the missing ending tag for the ajax model, but I'm getting a new nilClass error for lectures. I'm trying to use locals to pass it in, but I have no idea why @lecture is not being passed through. Any insight here would be greatly appreciated, I'm new to ajax. I made an EDIT to my original post with the new code I'm using up above. Thanks again.